# Hinge faces on edge?

Tags: edges, extrude

I want to recess the three triangular faces shown in the image into the back of the hand, but want them to "hinge" on the highlighted edges so the recess is at an angle. Second image is what I am trying to accomplish. How would I go about doing this?

[image: Hinged edge]
[image: Back of palm]

Comment: Might be easier to do them individually with the cursor as the pivot point in the middle of the bottom edge.

Comment: Still new to Blender - can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Select your edge that is highlighted, shift-s snap cursor to selection, and select the faces you want to move. Press the period key to change pivot to 3d cursor and then the rotation will pivot on the cursor. If you need to, change the Transform orientation to 'Normal'.